# How do I merge two DataFrame on a column with duplicates, and output without duplicates row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, duplicates

I have two data frames df1 and df2 as shown below:

`df1:`

|  | company | occupation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | Administrator |
| 1 | B | Engineer |
| 2 | C | Engineer |
| 3 | D | Account |
| 4 | E | Administrator |
| 5 | F | Engineer |

`df2:`

|  | occupation | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Account | balance |
| 1 | Engineer | database |
| 2 | Administrator | chores |
| 3 | Administrator | calling |
| 4 | Engineer | frontend |
| 5 | Engineer | backendend |

What I want:

|  | company | occupation | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | Administrator | chores |
| 1 | B | Engineer | database |
| 2 | C | Engineer | frontend |
| 3 | D | Account | balance |
| 4 | E | Administrator | calling |
| 5 | F | Engineer | backendend |

I tried `pd.merge(df1,df2,how="inner")`, but always get duplicates row:

|  | company | occupation | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | Administrator | chores |
| 1 | A | Administrator | calling |
| 2 | E | Administrator | chores |
| 3 | E | Administrator | calling |
| 4 | B | Engineer | database |
| 5 | B | Engineer | frontend |
| 6 | B | Engineer | backendend |
| 7 | C | Engineer | database |
| 8 | C | Engineer | frontend |
| 9 | C | Engineer | backendend |
| 10 | F | Engineer | database |
| 11 | F | Engineer | frontend |
| 12 | F | Engineer | backendend |
| 13 | D | Account | balance |

code:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"company":["A","B","C","D","E","F"],"occupation":["Administrator","Engineer","Engineer","Account","Administrator","Engineer"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"occupation":["Account","Engineer","Administrator","Administrator","Engineer","Engineer"],"description":["balance","database","chores","calling","frontend","backendend"]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({"company":["A","B","C","D","E","F"],"occupation":["Administrator","Engineer","Engineer","Account","Administrator","Engineer"],"description":["chores","database","balance","frontend","calling","backendend"]})
df4 = pd.merge(df1,df2,how="inner")
display(df1)
display(df2)
display(df3)
display(df4)
```

Comment: Is your desired output accurate? I guess you may want to match the a certain occurrence of a occupation in `df1` to the corresponding occurrence in `df2` e.g. 1st Engineer is assigned 'database'.

If yes, then your desired output maybe inaccurate?

Comment: I think `frontend` and `balance` might be swapped.

Comment: Yes, it's typo, I revised it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to create a key column with [`groupby cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-cumcount) to track position then merge on `occupation` and `key`:

```
df1['key'] = df1.groupby('occupation').cumcount()
df2['key'] = df2.groupby('occupation').cumcount()
df4 = df1.merge(df2, on=['occupation', 'key']).drop('key', axis=1)
```

`df4`:

```
  company     occupation description
0       A  Administrator      chores
1       B       Engineer    database
2       C       Engineer    frontend
3       D        Account     balance
4       E  Administrator     calling
5       F       Engineer  backendend
```

`df4` without dropping `key`:

```
  company     occupation  key description
0       A  Administrator    0      chores
1       B       Engineer    0    database
2       C       Engineer    1    frontend
3       D        Account    0     balance
4       E  Administrator    1     calling
5       F       Engineer    2  backendend
```

---

Can also do without affecting `df1` or `df2` by merging on series directly:

```
df4 = df1.merge(
    df2,
    left_on=['occupation', df1.groupby('occupation').cumcount()],
    right_on=['occupation', df2.groupby('occupation').cumcount()]
).drop('key_1', axis=1)
```

`df4`:

```
  company     occupation description
0       A  Administrator      chores
1       B       Engineer    database
2       C       Engineer    frontend
3       D        Account     balance
4       E  Administrator     calling
5       F       Engineer  backendend
```

Answer (score 1):

You can synthesise the part of the merge condition required.  The position of the **occupation** within the data frames.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'company': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
 'occupation': ['Administrator','Engineer','Engineer','Account','Administrator','Engineer']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'occupation': ['Account','Engineer','Administrator','Administrator','Engineer','Engineer'],
 'description': ['balance','database','chores','calling','frontend','backendend']})

df1.assign(oid=df1.groupby("occupation", as_index=False).cumcount()).merge(
    df2.assign(oid=df2.groupby("occupation", as_index=False).cumcount()),
    on=["occupation", "oid"],
)
```

|  | company | occupation | oid | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | Administrator | 0 | chores |
| 1 | B | Engineer | 0 | database |
| 2 | C | Engineer | 1 | frontend |
| 3 | D | Account | 0 | balance |
| 4 | E | Administrator | 1 | calling |
| 5 | F | Engineer | 2 | backendend |

Comment: Is this not the same as my answer?

Comment: @HenryEcker semantically it is the equivalent.  tracking position using `cumcount()`