# Pandas merging two table with non-unique key and different shape

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I would like to know if it would be possible to merge two table with non unique merging key into as concise shape as possible?

My problem is as follows: I have two tables

| First_name | Last_name | Reviewer | Score1 | Score2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Terry | Bob | 5 | 3 |
| John | Terry | Alice | 4 | 4 |

and

| First_name | Last_name | Reviewer | Score3 | Score4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Terry | Dylan | 1 | 1 |
| John | Terry | Mary | 4 | 3 |
| John | Terry | Richa | 5 | 5 |

I would like to merge it into

| First_name | Last_name | Reviewer_x | Score1 | Score2 | Reviewer_y | Score3 | Score4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Terry | Bob | 5 | 3 | Dylan | 1 | 1 |
| John | Terry | Alice | 4 | 4 | Mary | 4 | 3 |
| John | Terry | NaN | NaN | NaN | Richa | 5 | 5 |

I tried this

```
df1.merge(df2, on = ['First_name', 'Last_name'])
```

but pandas does not know how to deal with the duplicates in First_name Last_name combination and joins all rows from the right table to each row of the left table, hence it creates table with 6 rows.

Is it possible to do the transformation that I need?

Comment: do you have any names other than John Terry?

Comment: I think you're looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68443465/15497888) `df1.merge(df2, left_on=['First_name', 'Last_name', df1.groupby(['First_name', 'Last_name']).cumcount()], right_on=['First_name', 'Last_name', df2.groupby(['First_name', 'Last_name']).cumcount()], how='right')` assuming you are looking to positional join.

Comment: Yes, I have more name than John Terry